# Android Java out.of.memory image issue

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

I have my program which crashed when I press a button I have set. Whenever I delete the images from my res folder, and stop calling the pictures with the button press, it doesn't crash with the error anymore. Does anyone know what in the pictures might be causing the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static int pChoice = 0;
    private static String pName = "";

    private static int aiChoice = 0;
    private static String aiName = "";

    private static String win = "";

    private static boolean end = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button rock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button paper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button scissors = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        ImageView player = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView AI = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        rock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (end == false) {
                    pChoose(1);
                    aiChoose();
                    dWinner();
                    status.setText(win);
                }
            }

        });

        paper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pChoose(1);
                aiChoose();
                dWinner();
                status.setText(win);

            }

        });

        rock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pChoose(1);
                aiChoose();
                dWinner();
                status.setText(win);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void aiChoose() {
        aiChoice = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);

        switch (aiChoice) {
        case 1:
            aiName = "Rock";
        case 2:
            aiName = "Paper";
        case 3:
            aiName = "Scissors";
        }

    }

    public void pChoose(int input) {

        ImageView player = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        pChoice = input;

        switch (pChoice) {
        case 1:
            pName = "Rock";
            player.setImageResource(R.drawable.small);
        case 2:
            pName = "Paper";
            player.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
        case 3:
            pName = "Scissors";
            player.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors);
        }

    }

    public void dWinner() {

        if ((pChoice == 1 && aiChoice == 3) || (pChoice == 2 && aiChoice == 1)
                || (pChoice == 3 && aiChoice == 2)) {
            win = "Player wins!!!";

        } else if (pChoice == aiChoice) {
            win = "It was a Draw";

        } else {
            win = "The computer beat you!!!";

        }

        end = true;

    }

}
```

here's the error log

```
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:646)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:375)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at one.imusing.rockpaperscissors.MainActivity.pChoose(MainActivity.java:131)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at one.imusing.rockpaperscissors.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18796)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):`enter code here`   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-09 15:14:36.196: E/AndroidRuntime(11510):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I take it you just have your images on your layout?

Comment: I have three buttons as well. 2 that I actually have listeners on to do something.

Comment: I'm wondering if for some reason the images are just way too big. Have you tried resizing them to a normal size? Otherwise you could try http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html the Bitmap decoding discussed here

Comment: The images are 393 KB, 352 KB, and 3.83 MB. Would I need to use bitmap stuff for that?

Comment: I see the problem being the 3.83MB image. You should scale that down so it is not big. In one of the apps I used a well designed background that on xxhdpi drawings only takes 152KB.

Comment: The file size means nothing.  What resolution are they?

Comment: I was hinting at scaling down the resolution so the file size is smaller.

Comment: I can make a 3.83MB file size bitmap which will load fine, and a 1MB one which will kill memory

Answer (score 0):

Your code and description seems to be like you are loading too many images at once. First of all you should Cache your images. Secondly load the images in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` Also re-size your images before getting loaded using `BitmapFactory.Options` and crop it to your relevant size before loading it.